# Google In App Purchases (Cross platform recurring subscriptions)

Tags: android, cross-platform, google-pay

We are developing an education app (a Progressive Web App), which will work as a freemium app. Users will have the choice to pay a 5-10 USD subscription to gain access to the ad-free premium version.

However, we are also giving users the ability to access their profiles on both web and android. With this, there is a confusion as to how to implement the google pay system.

For example, if a user wants to upgrade within Android (we will be paying Google 30% off the revenue),

However, how does it work when a user who has already paid through our website (through stripe or visa/master) wants to now use the app to access the premium content he has already paid for.

What are the possible solutions that I can implement?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how your API is working in the backend but one thing is sure you have saved all the users subscription in the database.

1. You can pass some **key-value** in API response at client side(Android app). On behalf of that API, you can make decisions about what to show in the app.
2. Get some request body from android (mainly User Id) when they are calling the API and make the decision on that basis of that and deliver the data...

Comment: Thanks, but would this be a valid practice under Google Pay policy as they sometimes reject apps that get unlocked for payment from elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, it is because you are using google pay for only payments... You have full authority to show subscription and non-subscription data doesn't matter that user purchased the subscription or not.